# bash script, using a variable.

Tags: bash, variables, input, literals

I'm trying to use a input variable $1 in a path

```
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
   echo "The Directory Exists"  
   files=`find /cygdrive/c/2014-03-19 -name "*ellow.txt"`
   for file in $files; do
   etc...
```

Now instead of using the date, I'd like to use $1 (as the users inputted variable) for which directory they'd like to use. /cygdrive/c/$1.  But I don't think this works inside back ticks.  Any suggestions?  I've tried assigning $1 a variable name but it's still the same issue of it taking it literally.  How could I use a variable in this path?

Cheers lads.

Comment: Have you tried it inside the backticks? You might be surprised ;)

Comment: You have a completely different bug here, by the way -- try finding files whose names (or directory names) contain spaces and see what happens. See also the first entry in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: The safe way to use find would be, instead: `while IFS='' read -r -d '' file; do ...; done < <(find ... -print0)`

Comment: ...or, for a longer discussion of best practices around taking actions based on find's output, see sections 5 and below of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: By the way, it needs to be `"/cygdrive/c/$1"`, **with the double quotes**. Otherwise, the name can be split into multiple `find` arguments rather than passed as a single one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, please create an answer with your cogent points.

Comment: @glennjackman, these corrections don't directly answer the question, however misguided that question may be, so I'm a bit hesitant to do so.

Comment: ...well. Given the proliferation of other, worse answers, I've done so.

Answer (score 2):

Expansions certainly do occur in these contexts. That said, there's care to be taken in using `find` correctly; it's easy to do things that break with unusual filenames, whether such filenames are created by software bugs or malicious intent.

```
if [ -d "/cygdrive/c/$1" ]; then
    while IFS='' read -r -d '' file; do
      something_with "$file"
    done < <(find "/cygdrive/c/$1" -name '*ellow.txt' -print0)
else
    echo "$1 is not a directory" >&2
fi
```

References:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (entry #1, on why `$(find ...)` is inadequate)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind (with alternative approaches)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 (on the need for the `< <(...)` construct)

Comment: Ah I didn't see your answer here and posted something similar. +1

Comment: Can you explain the rationale behind setting IFS? I get the rest of it.

Comment: @Emmet, setting IFS to an empty string prevents trailing whitespace from being trimmed. Notably, passing no destination variable name and using `REPLY` (as @anubhava's answer did) also has that effect.

Comment: @Emmet ...by the way, it's actually essential that it be `-d ''` or `-d $'\0'` (though I think this second option is mildly misleading about how the parser works), but not `-d$'\0'` -- the latter parses out to just `-d`, leaving the next argument's first character to be parsed as the delimiter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for that. It's a recipe to add to my snippet bag. The "oddball" filenames issue has never bitten me, but there's never any harm doing something the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, variables are expanded inside backticks:

```
> test=foo
> echo `echo $test`
foo
```

So your script should work as written.

It's generally considered better practice, though, to use `$()` (unless you need compatibility with older platforms that don't support that construct). This is nearly equivalent to backticks, but it allows nesting (and is a little clearer).

EDIT: Although this is the answer to the question as asked, Charles Duffy has pointed out a couple other problems with the script as it stands. In general, these issues only affect files with "odd" names (those including spaces and globbing characters), but if there is *any* possibility that your script will ever be run in such a context, then these issues should be taken into account. (And if this is more than just a one-off single-session function definition, then, yes, there's a possibility that it will be re-used in a context you don't expect.)

Comment: There are bigger best-practices issues here -- `$(find ...)` is just as bad as using backticks; both string-split and glob-expand your filenames when trying to iterate over individual results.